# GSuite domain alias for group

Tags: gmail, g-suite, google

I have a Legacy GSuite account using with pleasure for several years now.
Recently I've purchased another domain and I added it as alias domain to GSuite.

All my current users have now personalized e-mail with alias domain.

However for the new domain I would like to create a group e-mail that multiple users from primary domain would have access to and I can't find a way to do it.

Creating group is possible only for primary domain, and group does not inherits auto aliases from alias domain.

Is there a way to achieve such configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias domains do apply to groups whose address is in the primary domain, although it could take up to 24 hours to propagate.

Comment: Thanks Liron - It started working after few days, so it was a problem with propagation